# How do you cap the size of a table

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net

I'm trying to display the data in an SQL table on a web page as a table, and one of my constraints is that there can only be 10 entries max per table. Is there a way to make it so you can't add more than 10 things to a table?

Comment: Whoch dbms are you using?

Comment: What are things?  Rows?  Columns?  You could do a select top 10 * from table.  This only restricts the displayed results however, it does not restrict records that are added to table.

Comment: SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [YOUR TABLE] or if you are using `LINQ` you should use: yourList.Take(10). Can you put an example of what did you try?

Comment: Can't add more than 10 things to *which* table? The database table or the web page table?

Comment: @iakobski both of them

Answer (score 0):

There is no formal mechanism for this (at least in most databases).

One method is to add an insert trigger that fails when you attempt an insertion that exceeds the number of desired rows.

Another method is to use a numbers table, and to create the table with a `check` constraint:

```
create table t (
    n int references numbers(n),
    . . .,
    check (n <= 10)
);
```

This saves the trigger.  It would be nice to use a `serial`/`auto_increment`/`identity` column for this purpose, but they are not guaranteed to lack gaps.